# Solving Ordinary Differential Equation,

Tags: calculus

Does this ODE has an exact solution or not ? if it has an exact solution please help me to solve it if not what is the most suitable numerical method to solve it 
$$\frac{y'}{x}+\frac{y}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^2}=-\lambda-8\pi a x^{\frac{k}{L^{\left( k+a \right)}}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{L^2}}$$
where k , a , $\lambda$ and L are constants

Comment: This looks like it's just a linear ODE, though not a particularly nice one.

Comment: Note, You can't solve an ODE without giving your constants numeric values.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}-\lambda-8\pi a x^{\frac{k}{L^{\left( k+a \right)}}} e^{\frac{-x^2}{L^2}}$

Then we get
\begin{align}
\frac{y'}{x}+\frac{y}{x^2}=f(x)
\end{align}
we can transform this into standard form by multiplying by $x$ and letting $g(x)=x f(x)$
\begin{align}
y'+\frac{y}{x}=xf(x)\\
y'+\frac{y}{x}=g(x)\\
\end{align}
We get a nice linear first order ODE.

Comment: Does that answer your question?

Comment: Click the check mark and accept answer if that is the case.